# Compare columns data types and size in same database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012

I need a query that could help me to compare column datatype and column size between two tables in same database.

For example I have these sample tables in the same database:

```
Table Names
-----------
I_A
I_B
I_C
T_A
T_B
T_C
ABC
```

I have to compare columns data types or columns size is mismatched between I AND T tables.

For example, I have to compare I_A with T_A table and I_B with T_B table like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a query like this will identify column differences. If you also need to identify columns that exist on one table but not the other, use a FULL OUTER JOIN in the final `SELECT` tweak the WHERE clause to include rows with a `NULL` in either I or T values.

```
WITH
    i_tables AS (
        SELECT
              RIGHT(t.name, 1) AS table_suffix
            , c.name AS column_name
            , ty.name AS type_name
            , c.max_length
            , c.precision
            , c.scale
            , c.is_nullable
        FROM sys.tables AS t
        JOIN sys.columns AS c ON
            c.object_id = t.object_id
        JOIN sys.types AS ty ON
            ty.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
            AND ty.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
        WHERE t.name LIKE 'I[_]_'
    )
    ,t_tables AS (
        SELECT
              RIGHT(t.name, 1) AS table_suffix
            , c.name AS column_name
            , ty.name AS type_name
            , c.max_length
            , c.precision
            , c.scale
            , c.is_nullable
        FROM sys.tables AS t
        JOIN sys.columns AS c ON
            c.object_id = t.object_id
        JOIN sys.types AS ty ON
            ty.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
            AND ty.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
        WHERE t.name LIKE 'T[_]_'
    )
SELECT *
FROM i_tables
JOIN t_tables ON 
    t_tables.table_suffix = i_tables.table_suffix
    AND t_tables.column_name = i_tables.column_name
WHERE
    t_tables.type_name <> i_tables.type_name
    AND t_tables.max_length <> i_tables.max_length
    AND t_tables.precision <> i_tables.precision
    AND t_tables.scale <> i_tables.scale
    AND t_tables.is_nullable <> i_tables.is_nullable;
```

Comment: Thanks.This query working for me.But in some tables column name is different in T Tables when comparing with I Table.For example in I table(Column Name->QuanityAmount) but in T table(Column Name Qty_Amount).so what i have to make changes in that query.

Comment: You can compare by column_id instead of column_name by adding c.column_id both both CTEs and then change the final join from `AND t_tables.column_name = i_tables.column_name` to `AND t_tables.column_id = i_tables.column_id`